# Would like to know which is more optimal having a view controller container vs UIScrollview as a container?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uipageviewcontroller, uicontainerview

I am wondering which is more optimal to contain several view controllers with the ability to scroll horizontally to switch controllers. Having a scroll view and adding the views of each view controllers or have a view controller containers?

each controller would have a list that would fetch data.

Update: I started using UIPageViewController as a subview to act as a container. But so far some of the interactions like going to a specific page isn't as smooth.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to have a horizontal `UICollectionView` with the viewcontrollers as cell objects, that gives you a lot of control.

Comment: what if In each view controller i have a collectionview within the cells. Wouldn't that be heavy on performance?

Comment: The collectionview cells are reused (both in the page collectionviews and in the main horizontal collectionview, so if you don't keep any references anywhere there are max 2 in memory.